# Bidirectionnal cookies with Invoke-webRequest PowerShell

Tags: powershell, session, cookies

thanks for reading

I am trying to connect on a website with "Invoke-WebRequest" from Powershell.

The fact is that the website I try to connect to uses cookies. Here is how the site works :

On load of the log in form, the server gives the client a JSESSIONID (a session token). When the client submits his datas, he sends his session token.

If the connection succed, then the server answers a NEW session token. I can connect from my web browser, in the network tab from the dev tool, I can see :

[Cookies exchanges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohP7c.png)

Here is my problem, does anyone know how to send and read cookies at the same time on PowerShell ? (I can use another cmdlet if it is easier)

Here is my code :

```
#parameters settings
$url="https://mywebsite.com/directory/connect"
$domain="mydomain";$email="myemail@email.com"; $pw="uncryptedPWsentToServer"
$userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
#I wasn't on a "supported" web browser according the server, so it is the solution I chose.

#Here I save the first cookie with -SessionVariable
$R1=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UserAgent $userAgent -SessionVariable SV

#Here I send the credentials (email + PW) with the cookie I previously saved
$R2=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Body ("domain="+$domain+"&email="+$email+"&password="+$pw+
"&action=authenticate") -Method POST -UserAgent $userAgent -WebSession $SV
```

The ideal would be :

```
$R2=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Body ("domain="+$domain+"&email="+$email+"&password="+$pw+
"&action=authenticate") -Method POST -UserAgent $userAgent -WebSession $SV -SessionVariable
SV2
```

In order to send $SV as first cookie, and save new cookie in $SV2.
Unfortunately, PowerShell doesn't understand I use ***-WebSession*** cmdlet and ***-SessionVariable*** cmdlet in the same ***Invoke-WebRequest*** cmdlet.

If some of you know how to solve this problem, I looked for a solution, but most of the time I only found how to sent or save cookies, not both at the same time..

I thank you for reading !

Max.

Comment: Cookies are transferred through http headers. The server sends `Set-Cookie` headers to set Cookies in the Client, which you can find in your `R1`and `R2` objects. To send them back you set a `Cookie` Header in your `Invoke-Webrequest` with the `-Header` Parameter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Ho great, thank you, I'm trying it right now.
It also allows me to display the JSESSIONID cookie, for the moment I displayed it with "$SV.Cookies.GetCookies($url).value"
So double thank !

Comment: The Microsoft docs say specifically  "You cannot use this parameter [-Headers] to specify User-Agent or cookie headers." The only way I've found to set a cookie is here: https://blog.gripdev.xyz/2015/05/27/powershell-invoke-webrequest-with-a-cookie/

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1275923/using-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-with-cookies